# HTML/CSS/JS резиновый Input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Ребят привет! Столкнулся с такой задачей: Нужно сверстать резиновый input что бы при наборе текста он растягивался под содержимое и отодвигал все то что сбоку (если он в тексте стоит). Вот пример формы, надо сделать именно так же: http://significa.pt/enquiry/  Но как я посмотрел Здесь форма сделана через дивы и похоже все инпуты скрыты и из дивов value передается в инпуты и потом они же перекидываются на почту. Помогите с этим, как это реализовать?

Comment: Посмотреть реализацию на сайте совсем никак?

Answer (score 10):

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function () {
  this.style.width = 0;
  this.style.width = this.scrollWidth + 'px';
});
```

```html
<input autofocus style=width:0>
```

Comment: Вау, вот это решение. Я когда делал что-то похожее, не додумался до такого. Век живи век учись!)

Answer (score 8):

Атрибут **contenteditable**

Сообщает, что элемент доступен для редактирования пользователем — можно удалять текст и вводить новый. Также работают стандартные команды вроде отмены, вставки текста из буфера и др. ([источник: Атрибут contenteditable](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/contenteditable))

```css
.input {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 28px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #dee1e5;
  color: #242A37;
  padding: 2px;
  line-height: 34px;
}

.input[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block;
  color: #dee1e5;
}
```

```html
<div class="input" contenteditable="true" placeholder="John Doe"></div>
```

А конкретно по вашему донору `significa.pt/enquiry/` - там нет форм и инпутов, но по сабмиту собираются данные из заполнявшихся клиентом div'ов, пакуются в json и ajax'ом летят в обработчик.