# Ширина input блока в html

Tags: html, css

Есть простой input блок

`<input type = "text" value =  "Введите имя" >`

Когда подобный input отображается в браузере , его рамка намного больше чем значение value,и тем более если ввести еще меньшее по длине слово.

Понятно что размер рамки можно изменить меняя size под свои нужды

`<input size = "10"`

Или подобным образом в css

```
input[type=text]{
   width:200px;
}
```

Вопрос! Можно ли заставить без js, рамку input принимать размер в зависимости от количества букв в значении  value, побывал  width: auto в css; Не работает.

Comment: нативно - нет. Можно js выкрутиться, но будут проблемы с определение ширины текста. Вы уверены, что вам это нужно?)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/648962/265406

Comment: Если не принципиально использовать именно input, это можно провернуть с другими элементами с inline-block и contenteditable

Comment: Спасибо ребят. И Nikita Umnov  и UModeL. В нативном варианте как я и предполагал такой штуки нет. Придется делать с js ,по ссылки что прислал UModeL, второй вариант с contenteditable интересен но имеет нюанс, если нажать enter то каретка перепрыгивает на вторую строку и делает input уже многострочным что не всегда имеет место быть. Но вариант с js очень короткий и у меня в голове он был на много длинней. Раз без js не выходит значит буду через js делать. Такая штука может понадобиться при переименовании чего либо. Например названия, папки, файла.Всем всех благ!!

Comment: contenteditable наиболее подходящее решение